# How to Adjust dynamic width of multi column list layout of CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to develop a vertical menu with multi-column list(li) layout using CSS3. submenu columns are generated using css3 with a defined height. So, the width of the submenu container(ul) becomes dynamic.

I have tried a lot to adjust the  **width** of container(ul). Can anyone please help me to do that?

Comment: Have you tried something? Show some code.